# Select all records from Table 1 but only the row in Table 2 with the max Version number

Tags: sql, sql-server, group-by

I have Table `Trades.Transaction` and Table `Trades.BondRef`. They can be joined on `InstrumentDescription` but produce one to many rows as there are multiple `ISIN/CUSIP` (BondRef) per `InstrumentDescription` (Transaction). I would like to join but only display the row from `Trades.BondRef`which has the max Version number. I have reviewed numerous posts and come up with the code below.

```
SELECT  tr.TradeDate,
        tr.InstrumentDescription, 
        B.maxVersion,
        B.IsLatest, 
        B.Isin,
        B.Cusip,
        B.RbcType1,
        B.RbcType2,
        B.RbcType3  
FROM [trade_management].[dbo].[Trades.Transaction] tr   WITH (NOLOCK)
INNER JOIN (
            SELECT  InstrumentDescription,
                    MAX(version) maxVersion,
                    IsLatest, 
                    Isin,
                    Cusip,
                    RbcType1,
                    RbcType2,
                    RbcType3  
            FROM [trade_management].[dbo].[Trades.BondRef] 
            WHERE ValidTo between '2018-10-30 00:00:00.0000000 +00:00' and '2018-10-30 23:59:29.0000000 +00:00' 
            GROUP BY InstrumentDescription,IsLatest, Isin,Cusip,RbcType1,RbcType2,RbcType3
            ) AS B
ON B.InstrumentDescription = tr.InstrumentDescription
WHERE
(tr.OrigSystem = 'RBCE TOMS' OR tr.OrigSystem = 'SALE')
and (BookingAccountType = 'CLIENT' OR BookingAccountType = 'MASTER') 
and tr.BookingAccountFacilitatorTeamCode in ('ESF','MJC','43B','DWV','G9J','698','9DN','A2T','AX3') -- HK Sales
and tr.IsLatest = 1 
and tr.Status not in ('Cancelled') 
and tr.TradeDate between '2018-10-30 00:00:00.0000000 +00:00' and '2018-10-30 23:59:29.0000000 +00:00'  
order  by tr.tradedate
```

I'm getting duplicate rows being returned as my groupby includes the Isin and Cusip. Note `CBAAU 4 1/2 12/09/25`  with `Version` 249 should be the only row returned.

```
TradeDate   InstrumentDescription   maxVersion  Isin    Cusip   RbcType1    RbcType2    RbcType3
2018-10-30  NESNVX 3 1/8 03/22/23   124 XS1796233150    NULL        CORP    INDUSTRIAL  EURO_MTN
2018-10-30  HSBC 6 1/4 PERP         116 US404280BN80    404280BN8   CORP    BANK    GLOBAL
2018-10-30  CBAAU 4 1/2 12/09/25    248 US2027A0HR32    2027A0HR3   CORP    BANK    PRIV_PLACEMENT
2018-10-30  CBAAU 4 1/2 12/09/25    249 US2027A1HR15    2027A1HR1   CORP    BANK    EURO-DOLLAR
2018-10-30  EIB 8 3/4 08/18/25      434 XS1274823571    NULL       SUPRA    NATIONAL    EURO_MTN
```

But if I remove them I can display the fields.

```
Column 'trade_management.dbo.Trades.BondRef.Isin' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.
```

So how can I retrieve the columns in `Trades.BondRef` in the Select staement if they are not included in the subquery?

Comment: What's your definition of a `duplicate row`?  It must be different to mine, as I can't see any duplicated rows in your list.  I can see an `InstrumentDescription` (CBAAU 4 1/2 12/09/25) appears twice, but other columns in that row are different between the first and the second instance.

Comment: I only want to see CBAAU 4 1/2 12/09/25    249 as this is the highest Version for that InstrumentDescription.

Comment: use CROSS APPLY instead of INNER JOIN, it's ideal for joining to TOP 1 subqueries

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of using a GROUP BY and a MAX you could use the window function ROW_NUMBER.

Since ROW_NUMBER can be given an order.
To determine which record will have row_number = 1.

And you can also combine an `ORDER BY ROW_NUMBER` with a `TOP 1 WITH TIES`.

```
...
INNER JOIN (
        SELECT TOP 1 WITH TIES
                InstrumentDescription,
                version AS maxVersion,
                IsLatest, 
                Isin,
                Cusip,
                RbcType1,
                RbcType2,
                RbcType3  
        FROM [trade_management].[dbo].[Trades.BondRef] 
        WHERE ValidTo between '2018-10-30 00:00:00.0000000 +00:00' and '2018-10-30 23:59:29.0000000 +00:00' 
        ORDER BY ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY InstrumentDescription ORDER BY version DESC)
        ) AS B
ON B.InstrumentDescription = tr.InstrumentDescription
...
```

Comment: Getting Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'BY'. Checking further

Comment: @PeterLucas Try again. I had the syntax slightly wrong.

Comment: Thanks @LukeStorms

Comment: Thx for the rep. As a side-note. It's probably outside of your choice. But normally tables don't get dots in their names.  Because a dot is used to separate the servername.databasename.tablename.  Mostly CamelCase or an underscore is more commonly used.

Comment: Cheers I'll take that on board. It's my Python background coming through  ; )

Answer (score 1):

You don't do anything to remove any non-maximum versions.  If you can use common-table expressions then this is just another step, to find the maximum version per instrument description:

```
WITH B AS (            SELECT  InstrumentDescription,
                    MAX(version) maxVersion,
                    IsLatest, 
                    Isin,
                    Cusip,
                    RbcType1,
                    RbcType2,
                    RbcType3  
            FROM [trade_management].[dbo].[Trades.BondRef] 
            WHERE ValidTo between '2018-10-30 00:00:00.0000000 +00:00' and '2018-10-30 23:59:29.0000000 +00:00' 
            GROUP BY InstrumentDescription,IsLatest, Isin,Cusip,RbcType1,RbcType2,RbcType3),
C AS (
    SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY InstrumentDescription ORDER BY maxVersion DESC) AS version_id FROM B)
SELECT  tr.TradeDate,
        tr.InstrumentDescription, 
        C.maxVersion,
        C.IsLatest, 
        C.Isin,
        C.Cusip,
        C.RbcType1,
        C.RbcType2,
        C.RbcType3  
FROM [trade_management].[dbo].[Trades.Transaction] tr   WITH (NOLOCK)
INNER JOIN C
ON C.InstrumentDescription = tr.InstrumentDescription AND c.version_id = 1
WHERE
(tr.OrigSystem = 'RBCE TOMS' OR tr.OrigSystem = 'SALE')
and (BookingAccountType = 'CLIENT' OR BookingAccountType = 'MASTER') 
and tr.BookingAccountFacilitatorTeamCode in ('ESF','MJC','43B','DWV','G9J','698','9DN','A2T','AX3') -- HK Sales
and tr.IsLatest = 1 
and tr.Status not in ('Cancelled') 
and tr.TradeDate between '2018-10-30 00:00:00.0000000 +00:00' and '2018-10-30 23:59:29.0000000 +00:00'  
order  by tr.tradedate
```

Comment: Sorry, fixed now.

Comment: Hey Richard. Getting a Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'FROM'.

Comment: Lol! Working!! Thanks Richard